# scanf continuously executing, not letting statement after it to execute

Tags: c

```
int main() {
  int number, factor = 1, temp, sum = 0;
  scanf ("%d", &number);
  temp = number;

  while(temp) {
    temp = temp % 10;
    factor = factor *10;
  };
  while(factor > 1) {
    factor = factor / 10;
    sum += (number / factor);
    number = number % factor;
  };
  printf("sum is %d\n");
}
```

Every time I execute program, as soon as scanf statement starts to execute it goes on again and again and program is stuck at entering inputs continuously.

Comment: `while(temp) { temp = temp % 10; ...}` will never finish unless temp is divisible by 10.

Comment: What is this program supposed to do? `printf("sum is %d\n");` is wrong, you probably meant `printf("sum is %d\n", sum);`. And please format your program correctly

Comment: Why do you think it is `scanf` that is causing your problem. How did you verify that it does not return after you entered the number?

Comment: maybe you mean `temp = temp / 10`

Comment: "As soon as `scanf` statement starts to execute it goes on again and again and program is stuck at entering inputs continuously"-- `scanf()` is not in a loop, is only called once. It is not possible for this code to get "stuck at entering inputs continuously." Is the posted code the actual code that has problems?

Comment: How do you even know your call to `scanf()` worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your program is supposed to compute the cross sum of the number entered.

So you probably want this:

```
int main() {
  int number, factor = 1, temp, sum = 0;
  scanf("%d", &number);
  temp = number;

  while (temp) {
    temp = temp / 10;
    factor = factor * 10;
  };
  while (factor > 1) {
    factor = factor / 10;
    sum += (number / factor);
    number = number % factor;
  };
  printf("sum is %d\n", sum);
}
```

There are two problems in your code:

1. `temp = temp % 10` ->  `temp = temp / 10`. `%` is the "modulo" operator, you need the "division" operator
2. `printf("sum is %d\n")` -> `printf("sum is %d\n", sum)`

So the problem was totally unrelated to `scanf`.

Answer (score 0):

```
temp = temp % 10;
```

Is the remainder when temp is divided by 10, except for numbers ending with 0 or multiple of 10, temp will never be 0 , hence `while( temp )` is an infinite loop. `scanf` read once.

Comment: Fixing temp/10 from %10 fixed problem but why was command line taking input continuously before fixing? Was it random behaviour due to infinite loop?

Comment: @Ryuzaki it wasn't, you just thought it was.

Comment: @Ryuzaki You can type anything during execution of any program. That doesn't mean the program is reading it. It means the shell is showing you what you type and if the program does not consume it, the shell will execute that next.